# asyncio: warn about long-running handlers

Tags: python, python-asyncio

With asyncio, to keep latency low, coroutines should not take a long time in between yielding.

To ensure that, logging the long runs might be useful.

A runnable example demonstrating what I mean:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from time import monotonic_ns
import asyncio
from pyaux.runlib import init_logging
init_logging(level=1)

state = {}


class LoggyLoopMixin:
    _warn_run_once_time = 0.2

    def _run_once(self):
        start_time = monotonic_ns()
        result = super()._run_once()
        end_time = monotonic_ns()
        self._check_run_once_time_diff(start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time)

    def _check_run_once_time_diff(self, start_time, end_time):
        time_diff = (end_time - start_time) / 1e9
        if time_diff > self._warn_run_once_time:
            self._handle_run_once_time_diff(time_diff=time_diff)

    def _handle_run_once_time_diff(self, time_diff, **kwargs):
        print("WARNING: large run_once time difference: %.3fs" % (time_diff,))


def mixin_asyncio_loop(mixin_cls):
    superclass = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().__class__

    # assuming that `superclass._loop_factory` is a class.
    # pylint: disable=protected-access
    class MixinnedEventLoop(mixin_cls, superclass._loop_factory):
        """ ... """

    class MixinnedEventLoopPolicy(superclass):
        _loop_factory = MixinnedEventLoop

    elp = MixinnedEventLoopPolicy()
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(elp)
    return elp


mixin_asyncio_loop(LoggyLoopMixin)


async def heartbeat(sleep_time=0.1, warn_time=0.2):
    """
    An on-top-of-the-loop implementation, which is even worse.
    See: https://github.com/pebble/event-loop-lag
    """
    prev = monotonic_ns()
    warn_time_ns = int(warn_time * 1e9)
    while True:
        now = monotonic_ns()
        if now - prev > warn_time_ns:
            print("Hearbeat missed (%.3fs from last)" % ((now - prev) / 1e9,))
        else:
            print("Heartbeat time: %d" % (now - prev,))
        prev = monotonic_ns()
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)


async def amain():
    # asyncio.ensure_future(heartbeat())

    sleep_time = 0.01
    while sleep_time < 3.5:
        print("Busy for %.3fs" % (sleep_time,))
        # await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)  # yield at all
        sleep_time *= 1.5


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(amain())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, I expected there to be already existing implementations of it, and it feels like I've seen this feature before, but could not find it.

And, [as it has been noted elsewhere](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/208), subclassing asyncio is discouraged.

Are there existing implementations of this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there existing implementations of this feature?

Yes, it's a [debug mode](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-debug-mode) of event loop.

Change your code following way to see result:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.set_debug(True)
loop.run_until_complete(amain())
```

You'll see something like this:

```
Busy for 0.034s
Busy for 0.051s
Busy for 0.076s
Busy for 0.114s
Executing <Handle ...> took 0.125 seconds
Busy for 0.171s
Executing <Handle ...> took 0.172 seconds
Busy for 0.256s
Executing <Handle ...> took 0.282 seconds
Busy for 0.384s
```